# Unable to fix Antd Modal Height

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am trying to set **Antd Modal height to 1000px by default** but its **not getting applied**. Please suggest where I might be doing wrong. Below is my code for the Modal.

```
<Modal style={{ height: "1000px" }} className="pm" width={600} title="Select" visible={isModalVisible3} footer={null} onCancel={() =>setIsModalVisible3(false)}>
    <span>Sample Text</span>
</Modal>
```

I even added `.pm{height: 1000px;}` in my **base.css** file but no luck

Please suggest a workaround.

Comment: can you try with style={{ width: "100%" }} please

Comment: @x-rw not working :( BTW, I want fixed height, not width

Comment: @user7396942

you may try this :  
<Modal width={100%} />

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this way

```js
<Modal
   bodyStyle={{height: 1000}}
>
   Your content
</Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks.... `'1000px'` must be in quotes, otherwise its throwing error for me